# Google Plus Android API: link to the post

Tags: android, google-plus

I am sharing something in Google Plus from my Android app. Everything works fine, but I would like to know the URL of the post. The call to the Google Plus posting dialog is done via `startActivityForResult`, which means `onActivityResult` will be called when returning to the activity. Is there a way to retrieve the URL, perhaps from the returned intent?